# Why, when calculating work done when a person climbs stairs, the distance is the height of the stairs but not the distance the person travels?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, vectors

I was thinking, since

*Work Done = Force * Distance moved in the direction of the force* ,

the distance moved in the direction of the force would be the distance of the slanted stairs instead of the vertical distance of the stairs, as shown in my school textbook. I had a little idea about this, that since the 'Force' is the weight of the person, it wouldn't make sense if the distance will be the slanted stairs' distance. The height is probably only used in that case if another force (e.g. machine pushing person up stairs) is used. However, I still can't quite get my mind around why height of the stairs is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, $W=f.d$, but this is a scalar product and $f$ and $d$ are vectors. Which means that the norm is $W=|f||d|\cos(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle of the stairs.
One can notice that $h=|d|\cos(\alpha)$ is the height of the stairs.

In other words, if you project all the vectors on the vertical axis, it becomes $W=|f||d|\cos(\alpha)=|f|h$

Comment: Please don't post formulas as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that to find the vertical axis cos(a) is used, but why is the vertical axis of the stairs (height of stairs) used instead of the slanted length?

Comment: Because the force acts vertically, gravity has no effect (no force either work) horizontally. So as the force is vertical, you take the vertical component of the displacement

Answer (score 0):

Since the only external force is gravity, and it acts *vertically* rather than in a slanted direction, only the vertical displacement matters.